How to package dependencies into an exe
I'm trying to package a c# project into a single executable including its dependencies. Whenever I go through the publishing Visual Studio, I end up getting a folder even though I ticked the single file option in the publishing window.

I've tried to build the project and have deleted my previous publishing profiles.

Those are native libraries
By default the 'Produce Single File' option only includes Managed DLLs (Dynamically Linked Libraries) or essentially libraries that are compiled to an "intermediate" language. They are considered managed because they require a runtime to compile them further to machine code before they are actually executable.
Native DLLs on the other hand are basically libraries that require no further compilation before they can be consumed by the processor. Again these are not include by default with the 'Produce Single File' option. In order to bundle these in as well we need to add the following directive to the Application Project File (.csproj):
<PropertyGroup>
    <IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>True</IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract>
</PropertyGroup>

Source:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=cli#native-libraries
I was able to reproduce what you are seeing:

And get it to one file (not including the pbd):


To even improve the answer, you could explain which setting did the job, why and where it is documented. (Additionally to the overview link)
